# TViewPort3D class in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have created objects of TViewPort3D - TLayout3D - TPlane - TCube classes in Delphi XE2 at runtime.

TViewPort3D > TLayout3D > TPlane > TCube is the creation hierarchy. Viewport3D owning Layout3D  and like wise.

I am changing properties like BringToFront, Visible=True and X,Y,Z positions as well as RotationAngles step-by-step as appropriate.

Also added two light sources one on left side of form and one on right side of Firemonkey 3D form & with the help of scroll bar changing their rotation angle so that light can fall on these created objects.
Objects getting created but can't be seen on the FMX form.

At designtime I can place the same objects from tool box and can see them in runtime. But can't see the runtime created objects.

*If required can share the code as well.*

Any help or link to further reading would be highly helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checked the Included FMX samples yet? I'm quite sure there's something in there you might find viable.

Comment: Always, always share relevant code (especially if you're working with things at runtime). It will surely help in this kind of questions.

Comment: I removed the fmx2 tag which seems incorrect alongside delphi-xe2

Comment: And I changed your title from "Delphi XE" to "Delphi XE2". You might want to edit it to be more descriptive too - perhaps "FireMonkey 3D objects are not visible at runtime" or something (I haven't changed it since I'm not certain I understand your problem correctly.) There's generally no need to include 'Delphi' in the title if it's tagged 'delphi' too.